# R: rvest: rank by Date

Tags: r, rvest

I can obtain text using Rvest:

```
library(rvest)
text = read_html(link) %>%
html_nodes(".r") %>% 
html_text()

text
```

But how can I rank the text by time?

Also how can I read the whole article

Can I extend the text to be 500 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls ask one question at a time.

1. Add the `&tbs=sbd:1` to the query
2. You can't, directly from the google result page.
3. You can't, directly from the google result page.